# How to automate Seasonal Arima?

Tags: forecasting, arima

I am building Seasonal Arima for more than 10k products. In all the tutorials and blogs mentioned, I need to do the exploration to find the p,d,q values along with seasonality value using the visualization plots.

But doing this analysis for 10k products is impossible. How can I automate the process? I am currently using the pmdarima package which has auto arima but when modelling for seasonal arima, it is expecting the seasonality time period.

How can I find the seasonality period with plots? Any statistical method or function which helps me here?